# AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

today my website suddenly stopped working. I tried calling godaddy tech support but they said nothing is working and to check the error log and hire a web developer. I just know how to operate wordpress, but dont know about technical stuff

This is the error log:

```
[Sat Mar 12 07:38:11 2016] [11544382] [core:error] [client 68.180.228.239:39540] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

This same error is repeated multiple times.

I tried searching on google but everyone said to change the .htaccess file, i did that but still nothing changes. Please help, i cant find any solution.

This is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I though WordPress used `index.php` and not `index.php?url=$1`...